# How to use :hover css when mouse is down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dropdown menu that's part of a JavaScript app. It's part of a row of buttons which are styled in a seperate CSS file. The dropdown menu creates a column of buttons that should be styled the same as the originating row.

I need the buttons in the dropdown menu to respond with the same :hover CSS as the row, but I'm having trouble because the mouse must be down for the dropdown menu to be visible. I can take the rules from CSS and write them into the JS like so:

```
    jQuery(texDiv).mouseover( function() {
      this.style.color = '#000000';
    });
```

But, I would prefer to reference the :hover CSS rule in some way, so that it is only written in one place in the code. I could just make all of the buttons' hover style be handled by jQuery mouseover adding a class, but now I'm curious about how this can be done.

So, how can I reference/force :hover CSS to take effect when mouse is down? Please direct me if I have missed this answer elsewhere!

Comment: hello, what selector is used ? does it filters only childs of first level: like : ul>li ?  | mousedown is equal to :actve in CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple solution - on mouseover add another class where you could define new color, and on mouseout remove it

Comment: I think what @Ochi meant - js: `$(textDiv).mousedown(function() { $(this).addClass('class') });`, css: `.class:hover {color: #000000}`. Just putting it out there to be sure.

Comment: without ":hover" part - just new class that is being attached and later removed

Comment: Oh - I understood it as that the rule should be applied when mouse is over the element **and** when the mouse button is clicked. And I thought that what you meant :) Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

To force a `:hover` wouldnt be understood by other browsers imo. You can define a marker-class in css like this:

```
// your seperate file
a:hover, .marker {
   // all your needs
}
```

So you can easyly add a css-class to your

```
jQuery(texDiv).mouseover( function() {
  $(this).addClass('marker');
});
```